# Blender with Threejs

Tags: python

I am using RvtVa3c to export revit scene as json, and using threejs viewer to render it. Threejs do not have Global Illumination hence render quality is not good.

I was thinking can I use blender as python library to accept the json models and create baked light maps for the modules and spit it out. Which I can use to render again in threejs viewer.

Please help if it is a right approach. And can blender be used in this way.
Thanks in advance!